# How to get a certain string in the middle of a my text

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have RGB color codes stored in my database, what I want is instead retrieving a whole rgb code e.g (rgb(0, 255, 128) I only want to retrieve the 0, 255 and 128, I tried using trim, but no good.

```
$sql32="select * from tooth";
$q32=mysql_query($sql32) or die(mysql_error());
$row32=mysql_num_rows($q32);
$r32=mysql_fetch_assoc($q32);
$rgbcol=$r32['t_color'];
```

I don't know what to do next when I retrieved the data. please help me

Comment: Fetch the whole value from database and the use regexp to parse it in php (like `preg_match`)

Comment: I can't use preg_match because my value is un predictable, i cant have a fix value on what to find.

Comment: What does your value looks like. Please add some forms. With your statement it's impossible to provide a better solution than those present. These match the only given example.

Comment: Ok, if you can't use `preg_match` maybe it's time to learn some :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regular expressions here would be a good idea

```
preg_match("/rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/", "rgb(0, 255, 128)", $rgb);
```

after this, `$rgb` will contain your color values

```
$rgb[1] == 0;
$rgb[2] == 255;
$rgb[3] == 128;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$r32['t_color'] = "rgb(122,132,244)";
//remove everything except numbers and comma
$rgbcol = preg_replace("/[^0-9,]/", "", $r32['t_color']); 
$rgbcol = explode(',',$rgbcol);
print_r($rgbcol);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 122
    [1] => 132
    [2] => 244
)
```